# Python, Networked programs from a book by Dr Charles Severance

Tags: python-2.7, network-programming

I am a beginner in programming, started from Python. I learn by Dr Charles Severance materials. So in his book there is an example:

```
import urllib
fhand = urllib.urlopen('http://www.py4inf.com/code/rom...
for line in fhand:
print line.strip()
```

When I copy paste it to Python 2 version (I use PyCharm 5.0.4) there appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "D:/Python4yk/temprehg111.py", line 2, in <module>

fhand = urllib.urlopen('http://www.py4inf.com/code/rom...

File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen

return opener.open(url)

File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 208, in open

return getattr(self, name)(url)

File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 292, in open_http

import httplib

File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 79, in <module>

import mimetools

File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetools.py", line 6, in <module>

import tempfile

File "C:\Python27\lib\tempfile.py", line 35, in <module>

from random import Random as _Random

File "random.py", line 3, in <module>

integers

NameError: name 'line' is not defined
```

When I type another example, gets an error also. What is wrong? I don`t even write a program. I just copy paste an example. Asked Dr Chuck - still no answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import urllib
fhand = urllib.urlopen('http://www.py4inf.com')
for line in fhand:
    print line.strip()       # notice the indentation
```